# Почему Android Studio ругается на метод setContentView?

Tags: android-layout

Только в одном классе подчеркивает красным, в остальных классах все норм работает, почему так?

```
class DetailFragment : Fragment() { 
 lateinit var detailBindingClass: FragmentDetailBinding 
 
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
 detailBindingClass = FragmentDetailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) 
 setContentView(detailBindingClass.root) 
 
 } 
 }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/andro…" 
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="match_parent" 
 tools:context=".DetailFragment"> 
 
 <TextView 
 android:id="@+id/tvNote" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:text="yes" /> 
 
 <Button 
 android:id="@+id/bClose" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="33dp" 
 android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
 android:text="@string/close" 
 
 /> 
 
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во фрагментах нет метода `setContentView`, в них ифлейтить вёрстку нужно в `onCreateView` и очищать в `onDestroyView`:

```
class DetailFragment : Fragment() { 
 private var binding: FragmentDetailBinding? = null 
 
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
   binding = FragmentDetailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) 
   return binding?.root
 }

 override fun onDestroyView() {
   super.onDestroyView()
   binding = null
 } 
}
```

Тут пример с ViewBinding, но для DataBinding всё то же самое
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments